# Weird error when using malloc in a function

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with the following code compiles without errors, but in execution the error comes *'Double free or corruption (fasttop)'*

```
void copyNoRepeat (int * v1, int tam1, int * v2, int * tam2_ptr)
{
    int i, j;
    int tam = * tam2_ptr // 0

    for (i = 0; i <tam1; i ++) // 1
    {
        for (j = 0; j <tam; j ++) // 2
        {
            if (V1 [i] == v2 [j]) // 3
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == tam) // 4
        {
tam ++; // 5
            v2 = (int *) realloc (v2, (tam + 1) * sizeof (int)); // 6
            V1 [i] = v2 [j];
        }
    }
    * Tam2_ptr = tam;
}
```

It crossed my mind that I was trying to do something that the compiler does not accept.

Before proceeding, a brief explanation of the code and my implementation of the function. I have a vector (v1) with repeated values ​​and want to copy, through the function 'copyNoRepeat', only one number each for the other vector (v2) that is allocated dynamically. Example:

v1 = [11,8,15,19,19,2,11,18,15,5]

v2 = [11,8,15,19,2,18,5]

(Numbers repeated 11,19,15, were not copied to v2)

In implementing the function 'copyNoRepeat' I can not use realloc to allocate more 4 bytes of space to store a number in v2, this results in "Double free or corruption (fasttop)." I wonder why?

I wrote another code to test if the problem was to increase the tam // 2, as I did in // 5, but there is no problem with that, I wrote in another file only this stretch and it works perfectly.

Another detail that I noticed is that just removing the line tam ++ // of 5, the error message becomes *'segmentation fault'*. If you remove the // line 6 with realloc, the algorithm runs as expected copying only unique, but appears the error: *'free (): invalid next size (fast)'*, I realized that it saves the values ​​in subsequent memory locations, but in free time to do it is not aware that memory was allocated for this data.

----------------ALL CODE-------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void geraValores(int v1[],int tam1,int limInf, int limSup);

void imprimeVetor(int v1[],int tam1);

void copiaValorsemrepetir(int *v1, int tam1, int *v2, int *tam2_ptr);

void checaValores(int *v1,int tam1, int *v2, int tam2);

int main (void)
{
    int limInf = 0;
    int limSup = 20;
    int tam1 = 10;
    int v1[tam1];

    int tam2=0;
    int *tam2_ptr = NULL;
    tam2_ptr = &tam2;

    int *v2;
    v2=(int*)malloc(tam2*sizeof(int));
    if(v2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro! Memória não alocada.");
        exit(0);
    }
    geraValores(v1,tam1,limInf,limSup);
    imprimeVetor(v1,tam1);
    //printf("Antes da func copia=%d\n",tam2);
    copiaValorsemrepetir(v1,tam1,v2,tam2_ptr);
    //printf("depois da func copia=%d\n",tam2);
    imprimeVetor(v2,tam2);
    free(v2);
}

void copiaValorsemrepetir(int *v1, int tam1, int *v2, int *tam2_ptr)
{
    int i,j;
    int tam = *tam2_ptr;

    for(i=0; i<tam1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<tam;j++)
        {
            if(v1[i]==v2[j])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == tam)
        {
            tam++;
            //v2 = (int*)realloc( v2, tam*sizeof(int) );
            v2[j] = v1[i];
        }
    }
    *tam2_ptr = tam;
}

void geraValores(int v1[],int tam1,int limInf, int limSup)
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    int j,k;

    for(j=0; j<tam1; j++)
    {
        v1[j] = limInf + rand() % limSup;
    }
}

void imprimeVetor(int v1[],int tam1)
{
    printf("Vetor:\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<tam1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d|", v1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Do a search for *emulate pass by reference in c*.

Comment: Also remember that [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) can fail and will then return a null pointer. If you reassign back to the pointer you pass in then you will lose that pointer and have a memory leak.

Comment: You are passing a copy of the pointer to int `int *v2`. Changing the value of `v2` via `realloc()` leaves the original pointer untouched. The newly allocated array `v2` may not start from the same memory location as the old array `v2`. In short, when `realloc()` allocates new memory, it `free()`s the old `v2` and if you `free(v2)` from caller, which is still pointing to old memory location, you'll be double freeing it.

Comment: This program doesn't even compile. First line is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the pointer you passed was allocated by malloc ? Isn't it a declared array? Are you sure that the end of the inner loop should be `SIZE`?

Comment: I suggest you print the memory location of `v2` before calling the function, within the function after realloc and before free in caller. You will see that the memory location pointed by `v2` in the caller is unchanged.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a debugging exam/test. Is it?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Google tradutor change the order. Correct: void copyNoRepeat (int * v1, int tam1, int * v2, int * tam2_ptr)

Comment: @alvits No, my teacher spent a vector exercise list, there tried to solve this problem with dynamic memory allocation. Easily solved by creating a vector v2 with the same size v1.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Need add test if if the pointer points to null, right?

Comment: In the `main` function when you allocate memory for `v2`, the value of `tam2` is *zero*. It's implementation-defined if `malloc` will return a null or a non-null pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `realloc` works fine in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `v2` in function `copiaValorsemrepetir` is not the same variable as `v2` in `main`. There are two variables, which I'm going to call `v2func` and `v2main`. `v2func` is the copy used in function `copiaValorsemrepetir`. `v2main` is the copy that is in `main`.

When you call `realloc` to change `v2func`, `realloc` frees the memory that `v2main` points to, and provides a new pointer that is stored in `v2func`. When `copiaValorsemrepetir` returns, the memory that `v2func` points to is lost (resulting in a memory leak).

The pointer in `main` still has its original value, which points to nothing. Therefore, the call to `imprimeVetor` is using a bad pointer, which could result in a segfault. And the line `free(v2)` attempts to free memory that has already been freed. That's why the code generates a *"double free"* error message.

---

To fix the problem, change the function call in `main` to update `v2`

```
v2 = copiaValorsemrepetir(v1,tam1,v2,tam2_ptr);
```

---

And change the function so that it returns the new pointer to `main`

```
int *copiaValorsemrepetir(int *v1, int tam1, int *v2, int *tam2_ptr)
{
    ...

    *tam2_ptr = tam;
    return v2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`v2` must be double pointer `int ** v2` because after `realloc` the new value of the pointer must be returned to the calling function (where it is `free`-d).

Comment: I'll try study to use double pointers too. Answer of @user3386109 work as well. I had a vague idea that the placeholder in the main is different from what is within the scope of the function.